# QBO3 Bulk Update of Document Template Logos

Tags: sql, imaging

Our company is re-branding next month, and we need to change the logos of several hundred document templates. We would like to "release" this change all at once, to coincide with the company's Marketing announcement.

Once we've updated the MS Word templates with the new logo, is there a way to bulk import them into QBO, rather than manually dragging and dropping each one onto the associated Document Template page?

Answer (score 0):

For each of the document templates you wish to change, prepare the new template, and then upload it to the Documents panel under the proper template, instead of dropping it on Transform field of the template.

[image]

After uploading your new document templates, edit them and set the description to 'Re-branding 2018'.

The day you want to release the re-branded templates, use the Import - Batch Apply feature to change the template's Transform to the uploaded version:

[image]

The gist of the batch apply is:

- Select all attachments marked for 'Re-branding 2018'
- Set their parent template's `TransformID` to us the re-branded Attachment